# Managing a huge number of extension methods

Tags: c#

I have the following scenario :
116 Extension Method to one object.
a main one called Process which calls other ones based on a list of function names.

and it looks like this

```
public static void Process(this myObject,IList<string> MethodsToCallNames)
{
   for(int i =0;i<MethodsToCallNames.Count;i++)
      {
          switch (MethodsToCallNames[i]) 
                {
                    case "SubProcess1" : myObject.SubProcess1();break;
                    case "SubProcess2" : myObject.SubProcess2();break;
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    case "SubProcess116" : myObject.SubProcess116();break;
                } 

      }
}

public static void SubProcess1(this myObject)

public static void SubProcess2(this myObject)
.
.
.
public static void SubProcess116(this myObject)
```

which is very performant but ugly, how would you go around this without using reflection?

Comment: Do you even call `SubProcessX` directly, without calling `Process`?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yes very often thats why they are seperated

Comment: OK, so my question is: *go around* what? How ugly `Process` method is? How many `SubProcessX` methods exist?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek getting rid of the swich statement if possible

Comment: At a minimum you should use a Dictonary instead

Comment: What is the reason to call `Process` with the name of the function to run instead of calling it directly?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp because it can be done without reflection

Comment: @Magnus a list of checkboxes that the user checks in the gui so he calls what he needs

Comment: This design sounds like it badly needs to be refactored.  What you should really be telling us is why you have this setup, and we can suggest a better way of doing whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft enlighten me, how would you do it? the reason i have it is because the user has to select what to do with the object from the gui and there are a list of processes each points to a function and some processes are dependent on eachother, but i often need to call the methods in code, which i do directly without calling the Process function

Comment: Put the extension methods in another namespace and only use that namespace when you want to use the extension method.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft it's an image processing app, i know that 99% of you might not chose this design, but i just hate design patterns and like to do it my way, the myobject is a wrapper for an Image, one function removes a solid back ground, one detects background color and decides if its solid and one recognizes all the text in an image and one is for recognizing numbers written over an image, i don't return anything i just modify the relevant properties in the wrapper

Comment: No one said anything about design patterns; this is just about having a good, easily-maintainable design.  Whether you work on large teams or are a lone wolf, that's something you *need* to learn as a programmer - even if you don't know it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prepare `Dictionary<string, Action>`, initialize it with all your methods and then simply call `actions[methodName]()`.

```
private static Dictionary<string, Action<myObject>> _actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>() {
    { "SubProcess1", (x) => x.SubProcess1() },
    { "SubProcess2", (x) => x.SubProcess2() },
    { "SubProcess3", (x) => x.SubProcess3() },

}

public static void Process(this myObject,IList<string> MethodsToCallNames)
{
    for(int i =0;i<MethodsToCallNames.Count;i++)
    {
        _actions[MethodsToCallNames[i]](myObject);
    }
}
```

***Update***

You can also initialize dictionary using reflection with Expression Tree runtime-compiled lambdas:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Action<object>> _actions;

static Test()
{
    _actions = typeof(Test).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                           .Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("SubProcess"))
                           .ToDictionary(m => m.Name, m => GetLambda(m));
}

private static Action<object> GetLambda(MethodInfo method)
{
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    return Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(Expression.Call(method, param), param).Compile();
}
```

I assumed your `myObject` is typed as `object`. Change the type to your to make it work.

Comment: Wouldn't the initialization be just as ugly as the switch?

Comment: @Magnus exactly, but is it faster?

Comment: O(1) instead of O(n)? it should be

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` lookup is *O(1)*, so should be similar to `switch`.

Comment: Just wondering, wouldn't it be better/neater to initialize using Reflection?

Comment: the lookup doesn't matter much if it is only 116 items.

Comment: @Abhinav Yes, that's possible. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek thats it!

Comment: This is one of those rare solutions that I call *beautiful*. Great stuff!!